# Bash and MySQL variables error

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, variables, backticks

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh    
Q=`</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c30`
mysql -uusername -ppasword accounts -e "update forum set key='$Q' where id='1';"
```

I have to add back-ticks (``) to "forum", "key" and "id", otherwise it returns me an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key='xdindSG7hK9KaYgs9RISJNqrzmn4LJ' where id='1'' at line 1
```

But if I add the back-ticks, bash interprets them as variables.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the single and double quotes.  Single quotes instructs bash to ignore the contents and you will be able to add your back-ticks.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  Then just escape the backticks by preceeding them with a backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Try a HERE document:

```
#!/bin/sh    
Q=`</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c30`
mysql -uusername -ppasword accounts <<HERE
    update forum set key='$Q' where id='1';
HERE
```

Try with

```
cat <<HERE
    update forum set key='$Q' where id='1';
HERE
```

Output:

> update forum set key='fnPIOid15anEJ2a3zVL6I1wbRjAKk0' where id='1';